# How to output the final tableau of simplex method in docplex?

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, docplex

Is there a way to output the final tableau in python with docplex library? If not, is there a work around?

I want to use dual simplex method to solve linear programming problem with newly added constraints. So, I would need to access the final tableau to decide which variable to exit the basis, without having to re-solve the problem from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of low level interaction cannot be done at the docplex level. In order to do this you can use `Model.get_cplex()` to get a reference to the underlying engine object. With this you can then get additional information. You can find the reference documentation for this class [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex.Cplex-class.html?pos=2). You probably want to look at the `solution`, `solution.basis`, `solution.advanced` properties. This should give you all the information you need.

Note that the engine works with an index oriented model in which every variable or constraint is just a number. You can convert docplex variable objects by using `Model.get_var_by_index()`.

I also wonder whether you may want drop docplex and instead directly use the CPLEX Python API. You can find documentation of this [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/help.html).